# how to use sprintf to prepend string with zero if the length of string is unknown or varies

Tags: php, printf

I need to add zero before a string which is essentially a number but can be of any length. How do I use sprintf to achieve this if length of the string can vary.

Below is the code I am working on

```
// $SKU is the array containing skus which has both numeric and alpha numeric values.
// I want to add zero only before those which starts with a number.

foreach ( $SKU as $key ) {
    $sku_first_char = $key[0]; // get the first character of the string. 

    if( is_numeric( $sku_first_char) ) { //if it is a number
        $num_padded = sprintf("CODE HERE"); //prepend it with a zero
    }
    echo $num_padded. '</br>';
}
```

Comment: You want to add exactly *one* `0` before all numbers? Or is there a more conditional logic to that? Like padding to a specific length?

Comment: It is just one zero. And I know it can be done by simply doing "0".$key. But I just learnt about sprintf and very much interested in knowing how can it be done using sprintf. Thank you.

Comment: `sprintf` is not really applicable here. `sprintf` can pad a string to a specified length, but since your length isn't specified, the best you can do is `sprintf('0%s', $num)`, which is pretty pointless.

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ( $SKU as $key ) {
    $sku_first_char = $key[0]; // get the first character of the string. 

    if( is_numeric( $sku_first_char) ) { //if it is a number
        $key = "0" . $key; //prepend it with a zero
    }
    echo $key. '';
}
```

No `sprintf` required.

Comment: I am aware of this solution but just interested in learning if it can be done using sprintf, hence framed my question specifically for that. Thank you.

Comment: @user2563864 That's rather pointless. Use `sprintf` for what `sprintf` should be used.

Answer (score 0):

Just for the hell of it:

```
$num = sprintf(sprintf('%%0%dd', strlen($num) + 1), $num);
```

This uses `sprintf` to pad the number with `0` to a specific length, with the length being dynamically set via a `sprintf` expression to one more than the number's length.

Yes, this is entirely pointless; just prepending a `0` to the number directly is what you really want:

```
printf('0%d', $num)
'0' . $num
"0$num"
```